# Count Elements of a Row above a Threshold in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have an numpy array:

```
data = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                 [9, 7, 3, 5, 8],
                 [1, 2, 3, 9, 6]])
```

I want to get the count of elements above 3 in each row:

```
[2, 4, 2]
```

Comment: `(data > 3).sum(axis=1)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
arr = (data > 3).sum(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> arr
array([2, 4, 2])
```